# Make Length property available for my class C#

Tags: c#

I want to create class Massive and to add a method for adding two massives. But property Length for my class instances doesn't work.

```
public static void Add(Massiv mas1, Massiv mas2, ref Massiv mas3)
    {

        if (mas1.Length != mas2.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!"); return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
        {
            mas3[i] = mas1[i] + mas2[i];
        }
    }
```

How to make it available for my class?
It's my code.

```
class Massiv
    {
    public Massiv(int n)
    {
        mas = new int[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
        {
            mas[i] = rand.Next(0, 10);
        }
    }

    public void ShowAll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Massive: ");
        foreach (var elem in mas)
        {
            Console.Write(elem + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void ShowElement(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("mas[{0}] = {1}", index, mas[index]);
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        }
    }

    public static void Add(Massiv mas1, Massiv mas2, ref Massiv mas3)
    {

        if (mas1.Length != mas2.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!"); return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
        {
            mas3[i] = mas1[i] + mas2[i];
        }
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return mas[index]; }
        set { mas[index] = value; }
    }

    private int[] mas;
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you defining `Add` like that, rather than declaring an [`operator+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s53ehcz3.aspx)?

Comment: Especially because, at the moment, your `Add` is broken in one of two ways - either a) you intended, but failed, to set `mas3` to a new object of the correct size, or b) You're not checking that the passed in `mas3` object is of the correct length to accept the values produced by the `for` loop.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to declare an `operator+`.  Is it right way?   `public static Massiv operator +(Massiv mas1, Massiv mas2)
  {
   if (mas1.Length == mas2.Length)
   {
    Massiv mas3 = new Massiv(mas1.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < mas1.Length; ++i)
    {
     mas3[i] = mas1[i] + mas2[i];
    }
    return mas3;
   }
   else
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Значения индексов массивов не совпадают.");
    return;
   }
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have not declared any `Length` property, therefore, the compiler cannot possibly know one.

Basically, add this to your class:

```
public int Length {
    get {
    }
    set {
    }
}
```

In the getter, you need to return the value of the property, while in the setter, you will have to change it.

In this case, you seem to want to retrieve the length of your internal array. If you do not need write-access, you can skip the `set` part:

```
public int Length {
    get {
        return mas.Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this property to your class:

```
public int Length { 
    get { return mas.Length; } 
}
```

Note it has only a `get` accessor, which makes it read only (You don't seem to need write access since you initialize the private array in the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Length {
    get {
        return mas.Length;
    }
}
```